# Solution of $xu_x + yu_y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the first order PDE $$xu_x + yu_y = 0 \; \text{on} \; \mathbb{R}^2$$ and I found the solution of that PDE is $$u(x,y) = f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = e^C = K$$ which is a constant solution.

So, my question is how can I find solution on puncture plan $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ that is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$ the equation becomes $\partial u/\partial r=0$, so any function of $\phi$ alone will be a solution. Now it's only a matter of finding some function of $\phi$ which is well-behaved on the whole punctured plane and translating it back to the $(x,y)$ variables. Can you take it from there?

Comment: can you please be more specific ?

Comment: OK, if you tell me where your problem is. Are you familiar with polar coordinates, to begin with?

Comment: I am sorry sir. But, I am not really faimiliar with polar coordinates. That's why I don't really understand how would the equation become in polar coordinate.

Comment: Polar coordinates are defined by $x=r \cos\phi$ and $y=r \sin\phi$, where $r \ge 0$. For a given point $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, there is only one value of $r$ that will satisfy these relations, namely $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but there are many possible values of $\phi$ (differing by an integer multiple of $2\pi$).

Comment: Now, using the chain rule, we can compute $\partial u/\partial r = (\partial u/\partial x)(\partial x/\partial r) +  (\partial u/\partial y)(\partial y/\partial r) = \dots$

Comment: $\dots=(\partial u/\partial x)(\cos \phi) +  (\partial u/\partial y)(\sin \phi) = (\partial u/\partial x)(x/r) +  (\partial u/\partial y)(y/r)$.

Comment: So $u_r = (1/r) \cdot (x u_x  + y u_y)$, which is why your PDE is equivalent to $u_r=0$.

Comment: And the solution to $u_r=0$ is $u(r,\phi)=f(\phi)$ for some function $f$ of one variable. But we can't take just any function $f$ if we want a solution valid for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, because of the problem with multi-valuedness of $\phi$. But, for example, $f(\phi)=\cos\phi$ has period $2 \pi$, so *that* function can be translated back to something which is nice in terms of $x$ and $y$.